# Modify Email that is associated to an existing Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud

In Exact Target, can you edit an email that is associated to an Active Journey?  Or is it best practice to copy the email that needs to be edited.  And then create a new Journey and associate the modified email to the new Journey?  I just do not want to break what is currently working.
Thanks
M

Comment: Also, the Journey is triggered by an Automation that runs every morning.  So could I edit the email if the automation is not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can edit the email after pausing but chances are that changes will not reflect in the email being used in the journey. Best way, is to copy and use new email in it.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the best steps to update your modified email in journey builder
i always followed this and it works

1. first pause the automation associated with your Journey
2. then go to your email do the necessary changes as you required.
3. now go to Interaction under Email studio

   - > left hand corner click on "Journey Builder Sends" select all emails
     >   you edited update all ,
     >   click on Publish
     >   then click on start
     >   now you can see all the emails will change inside journey automatically 
     >   now FINAL STEP go to automation which you have paused and re activate it

Comment: you do not need to sign a post here as it shows your user name and avatar under any answers or questions that you post.

Comment: i do not believe you have to pause, created my own answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you can even update the email within a running journey.

Just hover over the email activity and update it. Everything that has not reached the point of that journey until that moment will receive the new email version (if you chose the same email) or even a different email.

For reference:

Here is an older article with basicly the same question

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000DaGGQA0

Answer (score 0):

I still experience issues with updating a journey email while the journey is still active. Although the changes may look like they were reflected properly - when checking the Individual Email Result records on the contact, I'm seeing the old email being sent.

I would always, either stop the journey version and start a new version with a duplicated email - or build a new journey altogether with a duplicated email.